# Java - get the enclosing instance

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, inner-classes

I have this class:

```
@Transactional
@Repository("reportManagementDAO")
public class ReportManagementDAOImpl implements ReportManagementDAO,
        Serializable{
@Autowired
private SessionFactory getSessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
   return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
  this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

 class ReportWork extends AbstractReportWork{

 }
}//

abstract class AbstractReportWork extends RCDStoreProcedureWork {

   void doReport() {
     //How can I access to: ReportManagementDAOImpl.getSessionFactory()
     //using reflection, for example: 
     //Class<?> type = getClass().getEnclosingClass();
   }
}
```

How can I access to: ReportManagementDAOImpl.getSessionFactory(), by external class using reflection????

Comment: @david-basarab Can you people read the damn question before marking as duplicate? This has nothing to do with accessing non-visible classes. The word _external_ here means _outer_ class. No other similarities.

Answer (score 2):

If `AbstractReportWork` is also nested inside `ReportManagementDAOImpl` and is not `static`, you can just get the current outer instance via `ReportManagementDAOImpl.this`.

If `AbstractReportWork` is not nested inside `ReportManagementDAOImpl`, what you're trying to do is (while possible) a terrible idea because you're introducing a hidden (and extremely unusual) requirement that inheritors of `AbstractReportWork` must be nested classes. This is nothing short of a land mine, so don't do it.

Here are better alternatives:

1. If possible (i.e. if it's all stateless), `@Autowire SessionFactory` into the class where you need it (instead of getting it from the outer classes, or getting it manually from anywhere for that matter)
2. Otherwise, pass an instance of `ReportManagementDAO` or `SessionFactory` to `ReportWork` if it is needed (possibly by making `doReport()` accept it: `doReport(SessionFactory sessFactory){...}` or by making the constructor accept it: `ReportWork(SessionFactory sessFactory) {...}`)

If you really want to watch the world burn, reflectively get the enclosing instance:

```
Field this$0 = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("this$0");
//not sure if this$0.setAccessible(true); is required
ReportManagementDAO enclosing = (ReportManagementDAO) this$0.get(this);
enclosing.getSessionFactory();
```

But be warned, this is a hack that can and will break in future Java versions because the `this$0` field is in no way a part of the documented API.